# PHP Float and Double datatype in microtime()

Tags: php, casting, microtime

I am trying to understand how the various data types are controlling the way output of microtime() function is displayed?

here are the 3 scenarios:

**1** . This will display the output of the microtime function in floating format since I have set the boolean value to true.

I want to know, how many decimal places by default will the float function display (in this case it is 4)?

How is that related to the architecture of the CPU?

```
lab$ php -r 'echo microtime(true),"\n";'
1361544317.2586
```

**2** . Here, the output of microtime() function is being type cast to double format.

So, does it mean, it will show only upto 6 decimal places of microseconds? How is it different from float and its maximum size/precision?

```
lab$ php -r 'echo (double)microtime(),"\n";'
0.751238
```

**3** . This is the default usage of microtime() function, where it prints both the microseconds and the unix epoch timestamp:

```
lab$ php -r 'echo microtime(),"\n";' output: 0.27127200 1361544378
```

I wanted to understand this, because in many places I have seen that microtime() is being used to generate the seed for mt_rand() PRNG in this way:

```
mt_srand((double)microtime() * 1000000)
```

What is the use of typecasting here and multiplying with 10^6? And what is the maximum possible value of the parameter to mt_srand()?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is one problem with floating point numbers: You can either have large numbers or a high floating point precision. This problem doesn't fit to the problem of a large number of seconds (seconds since 1970/1/1) and a high precison - microseconds.

---

PHP tries to solve that issue by returning the floating point part of the timestamp and the number of full seconds since the epoch as two separated values in a string.

For situations where the precision is less important PHP also supports returning the timestamp as a float value, rounded to the nearest microsecond. On my system the accuracy is a 10.000th's second as in your example. I don't know if this is granted.

Quote from the PHP manual:

> By default, microtime() returns a string in the form "msec sec", where sec is the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix epoch (0:00:00 January 1, 1970 GMT), and msec is the number of microseconds that have elapsed since sec expressed in seconds.
>
> If get_as_float is set to TRUE, then microtime() returns a float, which represents the current time in seconds since the Unix epoch **accurate to the nearest microsecond**.

This means, if you need the most accurate precision you should use `microtime()` without the param `get_as_float` and then create the final timestamp using string and / or bc_math operations.